# A variable defined in the if block loses its value when it gets out of the if scope

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
function generateTimeStamp(currentDate = null) {
  if (!currentDate) {
    let hours = Math.round(1+(23*Math.random()));
    console.log('hours is ' + hours.toString());
  } else {
    let hours = currentDate.getHours();
  }
  if (hours < 10) {hours = "0" + hours;}
  return hours;
```

As you can see, I define the variable `hours` in a way or the other depending on the fact that the parameter `currentDate` is (or not) `null`, but I define it in any case.

If you see inside the first `if` block, the `console.log()` logs me correctly the value of the variable `hours`.

However, right after (when I try to perform the last instruction before `return`), I get an exception saying `hours is not defined`.

- Why does the variable `hours` loses its value outside the if block?
- How can I fix my issue?

Here a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdm6a37x/1/) to play around.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav

Comment: Do you understand variable scope and what `let` is used for?

Comment: `let` is *specifically* block scoped.

Comment: You should put `let hours` before `if(!currentDate)`, and assign the value to `hours` in you if blocks.
Or simply change `let` to `var`.

Comment: variables (especially `let` variables) try to exist within the scope that they are defined.  This lets you use the same variable name in a different scope without fear of overwriting something you may have needed elsewhere. In your code, initiating `hours` before `if(!currentDate)` will let you use and modify the variable inside the `if/else` and return it afterwards.

Comment: Please look at this [**JavaScript Guide**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) - Look for Variable Scope, which also mentions `let` specifically.

Comment: @deceze, all, thanks for your answers. I know about variable scope, but didn't know about this specificity of let. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @3142maple Suggesting to simply change `let` to `var`, while it "fixes" the issue incidentally, it is not good. To suggest declaration overwrites in code it never a good idea. In the context of the question either `let` or `var` should move to the top of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you defined the variable with `let` within the `if` block so it is only available in that scope. Unlike `var` the `let` keyword is block scoped. You have to put it outside the `if` statement if you want to use `let` over `var` like this:

```
function generateTimeStamp(currentDate = null) {
  let hours;      
  if (!currentDate) {
    hours = Math.round(1+(23*Math.random()));
    console.log('hours is ' + hours.toString());
  } else {
    hours = currentDate.getHours();
  }
  if (hours < 10) {hours = "0" + hours;}
  return hours;
}
```